# Error While validating the service descriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a demo to present DapperExtensions benefits. I'm stuck at a point. While starting the project I get a error about servicetype.
The error :

> "Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.Interfaces.DT_Inspection.ICityRepository Lifetime:
> Transient ImplementationType:
> ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.Repositories.DT_Inspection.CityRepository': Unable
> to resolve service for type 'ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.Dapper.IDbContext'
> while attempting to activate
> 'ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.Repositories.DT_Inspection.CityRepository'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve
> service for type 'ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.Dapper.IDbContext' while
> attempting to activate
> 'ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.Repositories.DT_Inspection.CityRepository'.)'"

DapperContext.cs

```
namespace ImOnTech.Teftis.DAL.Dapper
{
    public class DapperContext : IDbContext
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private IDbConnection _connection;

        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public DapperContext(IConfiguration _configuration)
        {
            configuration = _configuration;
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_connection != null && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                _connection.Close();
        }

        public IDbConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                if (_connection == null)
                {
                    _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                }
                if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) _connection.Open();
                return _connection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the CityRepository

```
public class CityRepository : ICityRepository
{
    public IDbContext Context { get; }
    public CityRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }       
   

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<City>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var CityList = await Context.Connection.GetListAsync<City>();
        Context.Connection.Close();
        return CityList.ToList();
        // var sql = "SELECT * FROM [DT_Inspection].City";
        //using (var connection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
        //{
        //    connection.Open();
        //    var result = await connection.QueryAsync<City>(sql);
        //    return result.ToList();
        //}
    }
```

And finally, CityController

```
 public class CityController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
   

    private readonly ILogger<CityController> _logger;

    public CityController(ILogger<CityController> logger, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
          
  
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var data = await unitOfWork.Cities.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(data);
    }
}
```

P.S. :

```
services.AddTransient<ICityRepository, CityRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

I add them into startup.cs already but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

add service dapper context in program.cs will be resolve problem.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sql-db-fusioncache/blob/25a8b23bfd281f1a2a0a53a074c48165f50ae352/src/WebApi1/Program.cs#L20

```
// ADD SERVICES: DAPPER CONTEXT
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DapperContext>(new DapperContext(sqlConn));
```

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
            services.AddTransient<IDbContext, DapperContext>();
```

solved the problem.